# i want to use my mobile as an emulator but when i connect my mobile to pc and start the debugging usb im using 4.2.2

Tags: android

i want to use my mobile as an emulator but when i connect my mobile to pc and start the debugging usb and run the app it shows me output no emulator found and when I search the emultr my mobile is not showing in the list
im using android 4.2.2

Comment: have you enable usb debugging on your device?

Answer (score 0):

- Enable the USB debugging
- Enable USB Tethering
- You must have appropriate drivers installed on your System

Answer (score 0):

connect your mobile to pc.Enable the usb debugging tool in your mobile and install Adb Driver Installer (9.0 MB)

http://adbdriver.com/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

Step by step how to enable usb debugging on your device:

- Firstly, you shoudl enable **Developer Options** on your mobile phone. How to do that is changes with respect to your phone's model. Check this [example link](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-enable-developer-settings-android-42)
- Then, you should enable **Usb Debugging** on your device. Check this [example link](http://www.phonearena.com/news/How-to-enable-USB-debugging-on-Android_id53909)
- Last step is downloading google_usb_driver for android as your devices driver from [this link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)

Finally, you are able to use your device as emulator.

Good luck.